# Implementar Loader enquanto carrega a página

Tags: javascript, html, http

Gostaria de entender melhor um recurso bastante usado em sistemas web onde você acessa uma página ele exibe um 'loader' enquanto o conteúdo não está pronto.

Como implementar isso em um sistema PHP que faz alguns procedimentos entrega para o front-end que também manipula alguns DOM's?

Comment: Amigo, geralmente eu uso isso quando carrego uma página em AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Bota uma `<div>` com

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 100;
```

Dentro dela você coloca sua imagem loader, só fazer o estilo pra centralizar ela.

Ai é só fazer a lógica para ela aparecer ou esconder.

Ex:

```
<div id="meuLoader">...</div>

<script>
    // rolou algum processamento no seu .php ou vc fez um ajax
    $('#meuLoader').addClass('hidden'); // classe do bootstrap que coloca estilo 'display: none';
</script>
```